# Google Map, use MarkerClusterer with FusionTables data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, markerclusterer

I'm trying to make a map with Google Map API and MarkerClusterer. It's works perfect with a simple JSON file (like this http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/simple_example.html).

But I would use Fusion Tables (simple to edit/add/del markers): http://www.google.com/drive/apps.html#fusiontables.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. You may request FusionTable-data via the [FusionTables-API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#queryData). This may be done on serverside, but also via AJAX(the API supports JSONP). Once you got the data the workflow will be similar to the JSON-example in your question.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_API_v1_clusteredMarkers.html?lat=14.639390&lng=269.479523&zoom=11&type=m&tablequery=SELECT%20geometry,%20name,%20description%20FROM&tableid=1npi-QWwoZ6LP_9wwHiwiG2omzMm6R9Qoj5aMjkM&where=)